# Diagnose rotation problems on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, rotation, orientation

I am having a weird problem with keeping orientation on the iPad. Very rarely, when I swap in and out view controllers, my view is displayed as portrait, even though my device is in landscape mode.

What should I do to resolve this problem? I have already set my controllers to landscape using shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method. Also, it appears only very rarely, making tracking the bug very difficult.

Is there a faster way to find out why the orientation is wrong, besides going through each controller?

Comment: on the interface builder set the properties of the simulated metrics orientation to inferred (or landscape if they are always landscape)

Comment: I am doing this in code, and I have set the orientation to landscape in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: you mean you are not using the IB at all? because even if you set it in code sometimes there is a conflict if you dont set it in the IB as well. The should autorotate is not related to the IB. the IB settings specify the starting position, if when the screen is presented there is no system request to change orientation then it will appear in the one specified here by default.

Comment: it might be because in info.plist the default orientation is portrait for ur application

Answer (score 0):

I see your comment that you are managing orientation by code using "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation", that is specifically an iOS5 method. By any chance is the iPad iOS6? If it is, you need to back it up with "supportedInterfaceOrientations".